# OnKeyListener only working within emulator

Tags: java, android, boolean

Hi people of stack......

I am having some issues on getting my onKeyListener to work. Basically as you can see below I want to start an intent on button click and also onKeyListener on the EditText box.

The Button click (public void sendip) is working fine, also the onKeyListener (listening to the enter key) works fine in the emulator. But as soon as I try pressing the "Enter" key on an actual android device it does not work.

Anyway shed any ideas..... would be much appreciated.......

```
package com.smarte.smartipcontrol;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class IPEntry extends Activity implements OnKeyListener {
public final static String ACTUALSMARTIP = "com.smarte.smartipcontrol.ACTU_IP";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_ipentry);
    savediP =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.serverIpAddress);
    savediP.setOnKeyListener(this);
}


protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(0); 
    String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
    if (restoredText != null) {
        savediP.setText(restoredText, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

        int selectionStart = prefs.getInt("selection-start", -1);
        int selectionEnd = prefs.getInt("selection-end", -1);
        if (selectionStart != -1 && selectionEnd != -1) {
            savediP.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
        }
    }
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();
    editor.putString("text", savediP.getText().toString());
    editor.putInt("selection-start", savediP.getSelectionStart());
    editor.putInt("selection-end", savediP.getSelectionEnd());
    editor.commit();
}

private EditText savediP;




//@Override
//public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.act_ipentry, menu);
    //return true;
//}


public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

 if (keyCode == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH ||
  keyCode == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||
  event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
  event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

  if (!event.isShiftPressed()) {
   Log.v("AndroidEnterKeyActivity","Enter Key Pressed!");
   switch (view.getId()) {
   case R.id.serverIpAddress:
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, IPControl.class);
    EditText ipaddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.serverIpAddress);
    String actu_ip = ipaddress.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(ACTUALSMARTIP, actu_ip);
    startActivity(intent);
    break;
   }
   return true; 
  }                

 }
 return false; // pass on to other listeners. 

}




/** Called when the user clicks the SendIP button */
public void sendip (View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, IPControl.class);
    EditText ipaddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.serverIpAddress);
    String actu_ip = ipaddress.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(ACTUALSMARTIP, actu_ip);
    startActivity(intent);

}
}
```

Comment: What is not working?  Crash? Nothing? Please specify

Comment: @jcw Its entering down, creating a new line in the text edit box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can fix your problem by giving your edittext the xml attribute `android:singleLine="true"`